# Display/hide a textfield based on dropdown value using React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to show/hide the visibility of a text box (here in my code as `TestField`) based on the value selected in a dropdown.

I have seen several examples where conditional logic is written inside `onChange` block but in my case I have to dispatch another action inside `onChange` whenever a dropdown option is chosen and therefore don´t know how to add a conditional logic.

Here´s my code so far:

```
              <InputGroup className='courses'>
                <Dropdown className = "course"
                  items={["Mathematics", "Geography", "Social Sciences"]}
                  onChange={(selectedItem: DropdownItem | null): void =>
                    dispatch({
                      type: "getCourse",
                      index: i,
                      value: selectedItem?.value
                    })
                  }
                />
             
               <TextField className=hours"
                onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                    dispatch({
                      type: "getHours",
                      index: i,
                      value: e.target.value,
                    })
                  }
               />
             </InputGroup>
```

I am pretty new to React and wondering if you could guide my regarding where to add the condition logic in my code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check your selectedItem

```
{selectedItem === 'what you want' && <p>Conditional rendering</p>}
```

Example ==> [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-elbakyan-yj0sb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)